# Copiar información de otro libro de trabajo en una hoja específica

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

Tengo un archivo de automatizaciones en el cuál tengo el siguiente código que falla:

```
 Sub Valores_LDAP_3_5y6()
   
'Declaración de variables
    Dim file As String
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim lCopyLastRowA As Long
    Dim RangoB As Excel.Range
    Dim carpDestino As String
    Dim Nombre_Archivo_Destino As String
    Dim liOrigen As Workbook
    Dim fecha As String
    Dim uName As String
    Dim carpLectura As String


   
'Establecer valores a las variables

    fecha = Format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy")
    uName = Range("F2").Value
    Nombre_Archivo_Destino = "Afternoon " & fecha & ".xlsx"
    carpLectura = "C:\Users" & "\" & uName & "\Downloads\"
    carpDestino = "C:\Users" & "\" & uName & "\Documents\"
    Set liOrigen = Workbooks.Open(carpDestino & Nombre_Archivo_Destino)
    Set Hoja = liOrigen.Sheets("Hoja 2")
    lCopyLastRowA = Cells(Hoja.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set RangoB = Hoja.Range("B1:B" & lCopyLastRowA)
    Set RangoA = Hoja.Range("A1:A" & lCopyLastRowA)
    
    
'Ejecución de la función
    While (carpLectura <> "")
        
        Set RangoB = Hoja.Range("B1:B" & lCopyLastRowA)
            For Each x In RangoB
                Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open(carpLectura & x & ".xlsx")
                Set rng = wbMaster.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1:B5")
                rng.Copy
                With liOrigen.Worksheets(x.value).Range("A1")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                End With
            Next x
    
            liOrigen.Close SaveChanges:=True
            Set liOrigen= Nothing
    
            carpLectura = Dir
    Wend

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

La idea del código es que por cada archivo dentro de carpLectura los abra y copie su contenido en la hoja del documento: liOrigen las cuales han sido creadas previamente con otra automatización.
Ya que posteriormente tengo que tratarlas en una table creada dentro de la “Hoja 2” del documento final.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Para hacer una buena depuración, al menos indica en qué línea falla y el mensaje que devuelve. 
Por cierto, en un revisado rápido del código, cuando indicas ("Hoja 2") quizá esté mal, ya que Excel por defecto a las hojas les da el nombre ("Hoja2") sin el espacio entre Hoja y el número

Comment: Buenas @pcandido ya conseguí hacer el bucle que necesitaba con el nuevo código que actualice. Respecto a lo que me comentas de la ("Hoja 2") si es correcto, le establecí yo ese nombre ya que posteriormente será otro nombre.

El problema lo tengo actualmente entre la línea:

rng.Copy
Set liOrigen = Workbooks.Open(carpDestino & Nombre_Archivo_Destino)

No me mantiene el valor de la variable "x". ¿Hay alguna forma de que me mantenga el valor de la variable de una hoja a otra?

Comment: La x no la puede perder, ya que lo único que hace es recorrer el RangoB...
Tienes que hacer una depuración paso a paso con F8, poner previamente a la ejecución un punto de interrupción en el While e ir viendo los valores (si pasas el ratón por los nombre de variables te da el valor que tiene en tiempo de ejecución, y también puedes usar Debug.Print nombreVariable y ver qué hace. Pon los Debug antes de la línea que te falla
Sin la estructura de ficheros y demás no puedo hacer la depuración fácilmente.

Comment: @pcandido Solucionado, tras revisar varias documentaciones lo que he hecho es eliminar la reapertura del "liOrigen" y poner (x.Value) para que lo reconozca y ha funcionado. He actualizado el código.